# a tag being printed alone in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code, for my wordpress front page, but when checking the actual result in html, the a tag is not surrounding the content. After some inspection, I have found that there is a problem with the php line to echo the category, but I dont know how to correct it.

```
        <?php
            // args query
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'order'          => 'DESC'
            );

            // custom query
            $recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);

            // check that we have results
            if($recent_posts->have_posts()) : ?>

            <ul class="article_list">

                <?php
                // start loop
                while ($recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>

                <li class="regular">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="category"><?php echo the_category(); ?></p>
                            <h3 class="article_title"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 80, '...'); ?></h3>
                            <p class="date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ); ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mask">
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" alt="" class="art_img">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif;
    // reset query
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has two types of post variable functions. `get_` functions will return a value so it can be manipulated and later printed to the document. `the_` functions do the same, however they automatically print the value to the document, and run it through any applicable filters.

*Note: usually they're more synonymous like `the_content()` and `get_the_content()`, but these ones are (imo) poorly named.*

[`the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_category/) is just a wrapper function that echoes [`get_the_category_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_list/)

Change:

```
<p class="category"><?php echo the_category(); ?></p>
```

To either:

```
<p class="category"><?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?></p>
```

Or

```
<p class="category"><?php the_category(); ?></p>
```

And that should fix your issue. Right now you're echoing a function that already echoes an output.

**Edit**: Based on your comments I now see that you mean the `<a>` tag is being printed on it's own. That is because `the_category()` and `get_the_category_list()` output a linked list by default. So you have the linked categories *inside* the existing `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">` tag which is invalid HTML. You can't have a link inside a link.

You'll either want to run the current function through [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) or use a different category function like [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) and loop through it

Comment: I found the reason, the a tag is being messed up, the category is being printed with an a tag, even with your answer.

Comment: Anyway,  I could learn something from your answer, thanks for explaining the system, and not only posting a code!

Comment: Oh my apologies I misinterpreted your question, you meant the `<a>` tag? Can you post the HTML markup that the code if giving you for that portion that isn't working correctly?

Comment: Oh I just re-read the HTML and figured out exactly what you meant. I've updated the answer.